# Laravel request ip returning null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in localhost trying to run a controller with this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
$transaccion = new Transaction();
$transaccion->user_id = $user_id;
$transaccion->event_id = $event_id;
$transaction->ip = \Request::ip();
$save = $transaccion->save();
```

But that is returning me this error: `Creating default object from empty value` on the ip line.

After reading around it might be because I use Illuminate\Http\ so I've changed to `use Request;` but the controller is big and is returning this: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$user_id` and I wouldn't like to change the whole controller.

I've also tried `$request->ip` but I think it's looking for some input and there's not so I get an error, I think it was undefined ip.

And tried `Request::ip()` without the `\` and returning `Request::ip() should not be called statically`

I think the main "problem" is that I'm in localhost so I don't have IP, but still, I'd like it to work on local.

So I tried some checks over `\Request::ip()` like:

```
(\Request::ip()) ? \Request::ip() : 0;
```

or

```
(is_null(\Request::ip()) ? 0 : (\Request::ip());
```

And some other but weirdly in all of them I'm getting the same `Creating default object from empty value`

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that is returning me this error: Creating default object from empty value
>
> After reading around it might be because I use Illuminate\Http\

It’s not. The error message is telling you exactly what’s wrong:

> Creating default object from empty value

The issue is with the `$transaction->ip` line. It appears you’re trying to set a property on a `$transaction` variable before it exists, so PHP assumes you want an object, creates one for you, and assigns it to the `$transaction` variable.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I'm still unsure why I'm getting an error on the ip line, and not in the rest. If I delete the ip line, the resto of the code works perfect. I've updated a little more of the code..

Comment: ok, I'm very stupid, I was using transacTion intead of transaccion (in spanish), thanks to your answer I've solve it :) because I was focusing on other things